# Delete all docs in Solr cause 400 bad request

Tags: solr

I created an xml file 'cleanall.xml' with following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>
<commit />
```

then issued following command:

```
java -Durl=http://localhost:8080/solr/update -jar post.jar cleanall.xml
```

and it returns #400 bad request. But if I issue another command:

```
java -Ddata=args -Dcommit=yes -Durl=http://localhost:8080/solr/update -jar post.jar "<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>"
```

then it runs ok. Doesn't `post.jar` allow specifying delete command in a xml file argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

post.jar automatically commits the changes to the Solr index.
Use only this -

```
<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>
```

So you do not need  in the xml explicity.

The 400 error is cause of you have multiple roots in the xml.

```
Error 400 Illegal to have multiple roots (start tag in epilog?).
```